# Execute a string after cut in terminal

Tags: string, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have a file say test.txt whose contents are:

> ID="1002"Name="gltestDmesg":Command="dmesg":

I want to run a command like this:

```
cat test.txt | rev | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev | execute
```

In place of `execute`, it should be such a command that will make **dmesg** to run in terminal. In place of `dmesg`, it can be any command that can be run on terminal.
I tried **xargs** as:

`cat test.txt | rev | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev | xargs`

but it's giving `dmesg` as output because the default program in **xargs** is **echo**.

I tried searching in several links but all says string manipulation using `cut` or `sed` but no execution after that. But I got to know about `xargs` but that also doesn't work.

Please comment also, if I missed something.

Thanks!

**Edit1**: In test.txt, there can be multiple lines in similar syntax, so instead of **cat** I can do grep also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the output as a command:

```
$(rev test.txt | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev)
```

The older form for this (still working, but you cannot nest it):

```
`rev test.txt | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev`
```

Alternatively, if you have to pipe it, the following should work:

```
rev test.txt | cut -d'"' -f2 | rev | sh
```

Comment: In solution(s) could be shorten from `cat test.txt | rev` to `rev test.txt` as `rev` could read the Input_file by itself too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, cat and grep can be more appropriate as the file may contain multiples line of same syntax.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R, we could do anything by using `awk`. Also `grep` could read any file by itself no need of using `cat` with it too.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R, sure, please see my EDIT solution too in my post now.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you on same.

```
awk -F"\"" '{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file | sh
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `system` function in `awk` too could help us here.

```
awk -F"\"" '{system($(NF-1))}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** For passing multiple files to `awk` you could use like eg--> for `.txt` files `*.txt` in place of Input_file above.
Or in case you have multiple files then you could do like `Input_file1 Input_file2 ...` too.

Comment: You could simplify your solution(s) by replacing `-F"\""` with `-F\"`